# Get certificate expiration date from certificate in file system

Tags: powershell

I'm using Windows PowerShell script to compare the expiration date of 2 certificates, 1 stored in the certificate store and 1 stored in my file system (C:\inetpub).

However, when i test the output i can't get the expiration date from the certificate that's not in the certificate store. It just shows a blank space when i use Write-Output to check it. Maybe my syntax is wrong or maybe its not possible?

This is what I'm currently trying:

```
$certName = "websitename.com"
$exportPath = "C:\"
$filePathCRT = $exportPath + $certName + ".crt"
$certSource = "CN=" + $certName

$srcCertFile = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\WebHosting | where{$_.Subject -eq $certSource}
if (!$srcCertFile)
{
    Exit
}

$desCertFile = Get-ChildItem Cert:\>C: -Path $filePathCRT
if (!$desCertFile)
{
    Write-Output "cannot get cert file"
}

if ($srcCertFile.NotAfter -ne $desCertFile.NotAfter)
{
    Write-Output "certs not the same"
    Write-Output $desCertFile.NotAfter
}
```

Does the certificate have to be in the certificate store to get its expiration date?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this statement: `$desCertFile = Get-ChildItem Cert:\>C: -Path $filePathCRT`

Comment: Open the certificate named ```websitename.com.crt``` at the location ```C:\```

Comment: Not gonna work, you want `$desCertFile = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new("C:\websitename.com.crt")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do:

```
$path = [path]
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($path)
$cert.NotAfter
```