# Powershell command to extract Expiry date of a .crt file

Tags: powershell

I am using the following command in PowerShell to extract the expiry date of a `.crt` file in a specified location (I am very new at this):

`Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path  C:\Onboarding\Certs\2023\Receiver\ -Filter *.crt`

This command returns the date last modified and not  `Valid from yyyy/MM/dd to yyyy/MM/dd`

Comment: Does this help? [Find certificate file expiration with powershell](https://serverfault.com/questions/738949/find-certificate-file-expiration-with-powershell) ... or this: [Find certificate file expiration with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73661104)